# ngrx store - select one entity to show in a separated template

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I have a blog application and I'm using ngrx.

the application -for now- have two objects in the store

```
{
"posts": [...],
"users": [...]
}
```

now I want to make a separated component to show a single post (selected-post.component).

I tried to select the entity by its id using a selector like this:

```
export const selectPostById = (id: string) => createSelector(
  selectEntities,
  entities => entities[id]
);
```

and then get it in the component:

```
postId: string = localStorage.getItem("_selectedPostId");

selectedPost: Observable<Post> = this.store.select(selectPostById(postId));
```

then to show it in the view I used:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedPost | async">
  <div class="post text-light">
    <div class="p-title fs-3">{{(selectedPost | async).title}}</div>
    <div class="p-image">
      <img [src]="(selectedPost | async).imageSrc">
    </div>
    <div class="p-cont fs-5">
      {{(selectedPost | async).content}}
    </div>
    <div class="p-category float-start fs-6">
      <a class="p-1" href="categories/category" *ngFor="let ct of (selectedPost | async).categories">
        {{ct}}
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="p-date float-end fs-6">
      {{(selectedPost | async).date}}
    </div>
    <div class="p-author fs-6">
      <a href="users/otheruser">{{(selectedPost | async).author.name}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="info">Comments</div>
  <div class="comments text-light">
    <div class="comment border rounded m-1" *ngFor="let comment of (selectedPost | async).comments">
      <div class="c-author">
        <a href="users/otheruser">{{comment.author.name}}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="c-cont">{{comment.content}}</div>
      <div class="-c-date">{{comment.date}}</div>
      <div class="replies" *ngIf="comment.replies">
        <div class="comment border rounded m-1" *ngFor="let reply of comment.replies">
          <div class="c-author">
            <a href="users/otheruser">{{reply.author.name}}</a>
          </div>
          <div class="c-cont">{{reply.content}}</div>
          <div class="c-date">{{reply.date}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

So the problem is that the post is not shown with error in console:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading: '1')`

I selected the post with the id "1" and it exists in the state shown by redux devtools.

Any ideas?.

EDIT:
the reducer:

```js
import { Action, createFeatureSelector, createReducer, createSelector, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import * as postActions from './actions';
import { Post } from 'src/app/models/post';

export interface PostState extends EntityState<Post> {
  error: any;
  selectedPostId: string | null;
}

export function selectUserId(a: Post): string {
  return a.id;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Post> = createEntityAdapter<Post>({
  selectId: selectUserId,
  sortComparer: false
});

export const initialState = adapter.getInitialState({error: null,selectedPostId: null});

const testsReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(postActions.loadPostsSuccess, (state, {posts}) => adapter.setAll(posts, state)),
  on(postActions.loadPostsFailed, (state, {error}) => ({...state, error})),
  on(postActions.setSelectedPostId, (state, {id}) => ({...state, selectedPostId: id}))
);

export function reducer(state: PostState, action: Action) {
  return testsReducer(state, action);
}

// Selectors

const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll,
  selectTotal,
} = adapter.getSelectors();

const feature = createFeatureSelector<PostState>('posts');

export const getPosts = createSelector(feature,selectAll);

export const getSelectedPostId = (state: PostState) => state.selectedPostId;

export const selectPostId = createSelector(
  feature,
  getSelectedPostId
);

export const selectPostById = (id: string) => createSelector(
  selectEntities,
  entities => entities[id]
);
```

Comment: It seems that your `selectEntities` selector returns null or undefined, could you please share its code also?

Comment: I updated the question to show the full reducer, the state is not undefined in the redux devtools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to link the `selectEntities` selector from the adapter to `feature` one (created by `createFeatureSelector` function), then use it to get the required entity by Id.

You can try the following:

```js
// Selectors
const { selectIds, selectEntities, selectAll, selectTotal } = adapter.getSelectors();

const feature = createFeatureSelector<PostState>('posts');

// ...

// Create a selector from the feature selector and selectEntities one.
export const selectPostEntities = createSelector(feature, selectEntities);

// Use the new selector `selectPostEntities` to slice the post entity from it.
export const selectPostById = (id: number) =>
    createSelector(selectPostEntities, (entities) => entities[id]);
```

---

Besides, you can optimize your component template by subscribing to the `selectedPost` observable using `asyn` pipe once only, like the following:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedPost | async as _selectedPost">
<!-- You can now use the `_selectedPost` variable without `async` pipe for all the elements inside the ng-container -->
</ng-container>
```